# Div class, show alert when div is in the screen but only once per div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I'd like to show an alert each time div class=promote is on the screen. But this alert may show only once per div.

My problem is, I cant get the data-id of the div and can't show alert only once per div when it is on the screen, only the first one is firing the alert and all the time.

Any ideas how to solve this?

```js
function elementInView(elem) {
  return $(window).scrollTop() < $(elem).offset().top + $(elem).height();
};

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (elementInView($('.promote'))) { //how to get any promote, not only the first? show alert only once per promote seen?
    var dataid = $(this).data("id"); //how to get data-id of the active class?
    alert(dataid);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class=promote data-id=1>div 1</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class=promote data-id=2>div 2</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class=promote data-id=3>div 3</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class=promote data-id=4>div 4</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y8fhnLt9/

Comment: May be that will help https://medium.com/talk-like/detecting-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-jquery-a6a4405a3ea2

Comment: $('.promote') may not be a single element, probably an array. $('.promote').forEach(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function you use to check whether the element is in viewport need some correction as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/tsq4ngcf/1/

```
function elementInView(elem){
    var shown = $(elem).data("shown");
  if(shown){
    return false;
  } 
  var elTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elBottom = $(elem).offset().top + $(elem).outerHeight();
  var screenBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight();
  var screenTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  if ((screenBottom > elTop) && (screenTop < elBottom)){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}


$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.promote').each(function() {
    if (elementInView(this)) {
        var dataid = $(this).data("id");
      $(this).attr('data-shown','1');
      alert(dataid);
     }

    }
  );

});
```

Comment: For that, you have to add some data property with div when it comes in view first time.

Comment: if possible, could you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this, note though that it is not really optimized as it loops through all elements on every scroll... some room for optimization:

```
function elementInView(elem){
  return $(window).scrollTop() < $(elem).offset().top + $(elem).height();
};

let shownElements = [];

$(window).scroll(function(){
  let elements = $('.promote');
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    let element = elements[i];
    if (elementInView(element)) { // check if the element is in view
      if (!shownElements.includes(element)) { // check if element already alerted/shown
        let dataid = $(element).attr("data-id"); // get the data-id value
        console.log("IN VIEW", element, dataid);
        shownElements[i] = element;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Updated to keep track of which elements have been shown already. So we fire only once.

http://jsfiddle.net/mxmz_/wzh2xvdo/24/

Comment: it is good, but it is firing all the time ;/ instead of the console.log I'll add a ajax, so I can't send an ajax call 5000 times per second... maybe using .next() or something?

Comment: Updated answer to keep track of which elements have been shown already